# Reporting every (optional) subelement

Tags: jq

Want to parse the following:

```
{
  "issues": [
    { "id": "1", "fields": { "links": [] } },
    { "id": "2", "fields": { "links": [ { "inlink": { "id": "red" } } ] } },
    { "id": "3", "fields": { "links": [ { "outlink": { "id": "yellow" } } ] } },
    { "id": "4", "fields": { "links": [ { "inlink": { "id": "green" } }, { "outlink": { "id": "blue" } } ] } }
  ]
}
```

into elements that represent the `links` elements, one for one, like this (note that `id 1` is missing and `id 4` appears twice:

```
  { "id": "2", "link": { "linktype": "inlink", "id": "red" } },
  { "id": "3", "link": { "linktype": "outlink", "id": "yellow" } },
  { "id": "4", "link": { "linktype": "inlink", "id": "green" } },
  { "id": "4", "link": { "linktype": "outlink", "id": "blue" } }
```

The following `jq` works for `inlink` or `outlink` separately

```
.issues[] | .id as $id | .fields.links[] | .inlink.id as $lid | {$id,$lid}
```

giving

```
{ "id": "2", "lid": "red" }
{ "id": "3", "lid": null }
{ "id": "4", "lid": "green" }
{ "id": "4", "lid": null }
```

but can't figure out how to track both types simultaneously or introduce the key `linktype`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -c '.issues[] | .id as $id
       | .fields.links[] | to_entries[]
       | {"id": $id, "link": {"linktype": .key, "id": .value.id}}' file
```

The output:

```
{"id":"2","link":{"linktype":"inlink","id":"red"}}
{"id":"3","link":{"linktype":"outlink","id":"yellow"}}
{"id":"4","link":{"linktype":"inlink","id":"green"}}
{"id":"4","link":{"linktype":"outlink","id":"blue"}}
```